# How to get a specific node value with VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

Trying to get a single value out of a XML file

with the code below I get a single line from the XML, but I only need the value of 0.816

```
<Value Test="Connectivity Test - Digital" Measurement="Voltage" Record="CLK">0.816</Value>
```

I can I filter out only the value?

```
   Sub TestMe()
     
        Dim xmlObj As Object
        Set xmlObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
     
        xmlObj.async = False
        xmlObj.validateOnParse = False
        xmlObj.Load ("C:\CobraTemp\pass.xml")
     

        
        Dim singleNode As Object
        'Set singleNode = xmlObj.SelectSingleNode("//Value[@Test = 'Connectivity Test - Digital' and @Measurement = 'Voltage' and @Record = 'CLK']").Attributes.getNamedItem("Value").Text
        Set singleNode = xmlObj.SelectSingleNode("//Value[@Test = 'Connectivity Test - Digital' and @Measurement = 'Voltage' and @Record = 'CLK']")
        
        Debug.Print singleNode.XML
        'Debug.Print singleNode.Text 
    End Sub
```

When I add the following to the debugPrint, I got an error Object Variable not set

```
.Attributes.getNamedItem("Value").Text
```

OK, just made a type in the code. Without adding the attribute for the text.
I just did

```
Debug.Print singleNode.Text
```

And that gives me the value of 0.816

Comment: VBA/MSXML supports XPath 1.0 so you can of course select e.g. `//Value[@Test = 'Connectivity Test - Digital' and @Measurement = 'Voltage' and @Record = 'CLK']` with `selectSingleNode` (might need to `setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath')` first, depending on whether the underlying MSXML version is 3 or 6).

Comment: Thank you Martin, really helpfull...but how to extract the value?

Comment: Use `singleNode.text` to read out the string contents of the element.